# C# - Get values of static properties from static class

Tags: c#, reflection, class, static, properties

I'm trying to loop through some static properties in a simple static class in order to populate a combo box with their values, but am having difficulties.

Here is the simple class:

```
public static MyStaticClass()
{
    public static string property1 = "NumberOne";
    public static string property2 = "NumberTwo";
    public static string property3 = "NumberThree";
}
```

... and the code attempting to retrieve the values:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyStaticClass);
PropertyInfo[] properties = myType.GetProperties(
       BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    MyComboBox.Items.Add(property.GetValue(myType, null).ToString());
}
```

If I don't supply any binding flags then I get about 57 properties including things like System.Reflection.Module Module and all sorts of other inherited things I don't care about. My 3 declared properties are not present.

If I supply various combinations of other flags then it always returns 0 properties. Great.

Does it matter that my static class is actually declared within another non-static class?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Veverke: Considering the OP made that mistake other people may too, so keeping incorrect terminology is crucial to ensure that Google is able to find the post. Such edit destroy the question, as there is no question left after you make that edit.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The problem is that `property1..3` are not properties, but fields.

To make them properties change them to:

```
private static string _property1 = "NumberOne";
public static string property1
{
  get { return _property1; }
  set { _property1 = value; }
}
```

Or use auto properties and initialize their values in the static constructor of the class:

```
public static string property1 { get; set; }

static MyStaticClass()
{
  property1 = "NumberOne";
}
```

...or use `myType.GetFields(...)` if fields are what you want to use.

Comment: I'm using something like:   
var type = new Foo().GetType();
var value = type.GetField("Field1").GetValue(new Foo());
Console.WriteLine(value);

Does that seem okay?

Answer (score 6):

Try removing `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`, because according to MSDN:

> Specifies that only members declared
>   at the level of the supplied type's
>   hierarchy should be considered.
>   Inherited members are not considered.

Since static's cannot be inherited, this might be causing your issues.  Also I noticed the fields you are trying to get are not properties.  So try using

```
type.GetFields(...)
```