# How to get fields and their values from a static class in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0

I have a static class in a refrenced assembly(named **"DAL"**) named "A7":

A7 like this:

```
public static class A7
{
public static readonly bool NeedCoding = false;
public static readonly string Title = "Desc_Title"
public static readonly string F0 = "";
public static readonly string F1 = "Desc_F1";
public static readonly string F2 = "Desc_F2";
public static readonly string F3 = "Desc_F3";
public static readonly string F4 = "Desc_F4";
}
```

How I can get All Properties name and values from **DAL** assemby A7 class?

thanks

Comment: Don't consider that My class is in another assembly

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Using reflection, you will need to look for fields; these are not properties.  As you can see from the following code, it looks for public static members:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = typeof(A7);
        FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(fi.GetValue(null).ToString());
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't consider that My class is in another assembly

Comment: @Nima The question clearly states "in a refrenced assembly" so it will work assuming you have the relevant `using` statements.

Comment: This is for the name but not for the value!

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue when i tried to get the properties using this syntax (where "ConfigValues" is a static class with static properties and I am looking for a property with the name "LookingFor")

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ConfigValues.GetType().GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "LookingFor");
```

The solution was to use the typeof operator instead

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(ConfigValues).GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "LookingFor");
```

that works, you don't have to view them as fields

HTH

Answer (score 5):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487867/c-get-values-of-static-properties-from-static-class) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451453/how-to-get-a-static-property-with-reflection) question.

As you will notice in the first question, you also mix up properties and fields. What you are declaring are fields, not properties

So a variant of this should work:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyStaticClass);
FieldInfo[] fields= myType.GetFields(
       BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
{
    // use f.Name and f.GetValue(null) here
}
```

Comment: GetValue needs an instance, but A7 is static.

Comment: @PVitt On static classes, pass `null`.

Comment: Ah, didnt see the FieldInfo type, thought it would be a PropertyInfo. My fault.

Answer (score 2):

somthing like this: ?

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = typeof(A7).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
    {
      var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
       return fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).Cast<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a reference to the DAL.dll(or whatever you've called it) file and include it in the using section. Then you should be able to acces the public fields.

Comment: But you wouldn't be able to get all the names of the publicly declared fields at runtime. That's why you want to use reflection.