# Access Dynamic String

Tags: c#, .net

I'm inside a for and I want to access to a Class.Constants. This Constants vars are in order like Constants.X1, Constants.X2....

I would like to access this constants inside my form like

```
for (i = 1; i = 10; i++)
{
  int a  = Constants.X + i;
  int b = Constants.X + "20";
}
```

Is this able to do?

Comment: No, you can't do it that way. Use an array to store your constants,and then you could access them like `Constants.X[i]`

Comment: nice idea, thanks.

Comment: Yes It is possible with Reflection. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334067/how-to-get-fields-and-their-values-from-a-static-class-in-referenced-assembly) post

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Make a class that contains your constants.

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
     public class Constants{
          public const int x1 = 1;
          public const int x2 = 2;
     }
}
```

You will be able to use the class directly to get the constants if both the class are inside same namespace. Otherwise just use the namespace to use the Constants class.

```
public class myTestClass{
     for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          int a = MyNameSpace.Constants.x1 + i;
          int b = MyNameSpace.Constants.x2 + i;
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand me.

Comment: Sorry. Can you please elaborate your question ?

Comment: I want to concatenate at the string not at the value of this. Just look the example: Constants."X1" or Constants.X + "1"

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question. I think what you want is not possible.