# how to use getproperty in constant c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to get the constant value using the siting value, but I am unable to achieve that can you help me to do so

```
using System;
public static class Constants
{
    public static class HostServer
    {
        public static string ABC = "abc.com";
    }
    public static class WMS
    {
        public const string URL = "/create/user";
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var x = Constants.GetType().GetProperty("ABC").GetValue(Constants, null).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `var x = typeof(Constants).GetProperty("...`

Comment: The question is though, why use reflection?

Comment: `var x = typeof(Constants).GetProperty("ABC").GetValue(Constants,null).ToString();` i got this below error `'Constants' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`

Comment: @DavidG can you suggest a sample for the above with an example

Comment: @SDeepakkumar you have that property in another class, it's not in `Constants`, rather it's in `HostServer`...

Comment: I mean, why can't you just use `var x = Constants.HostServer.ABC;`?

Comment: @zaggler is there ant sample code to achieve this

Comment: But if you REALLY need to use reflection to get ABC then try this: `var x = typeof(Constants.HostServer).GetField("ABC", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);`

Comment: @DavidG we can use what you have mentioned, but I will send a string parameter to a method to access the constant property

Comment: It looks to me like you're building up configuration settings. As mentioned elsewhere, reflection is probably not needed for this. Look into the `ConfigurationManager` class. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=net-5.0

Comment: https://xyproblem.info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get fields and their values from a static class in referenced assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334067/how-to-get-fields-and-their-values-from-a-static-class-in-referenced-assembly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to use `GetField`, not `GetProperty`. Secondly, you should specify the binding flags since constants are essentially static. And finally, you need to use the full type name of the class since you have nested classes. With all of that, this will get you the constant value:

```
var x = typeof(Constants.HostServer) // <-- Use full class name here
   .GetField("ABC", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static) // <-- binding flags
   .GetValue(null); // <-- static fields don't need an instance object
```

Comment: Work's fine thank you

Comment: @SDeepakkumar I would encourage you do some null checking, `GetField` can return `null`... So something like: `var x = typeof(Constants.HostServer) // <-- Use full class name here
   .GetField("ABC", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static) // <-- binding flags
   ?.GetValue(null);`