# Accessing the Properties of a class dynamically

Tags: c#-4.0, casting

Hi I have to different classes with Same properties and I want to access the peoperties of my classes Dynamically.

```
public Class1
{
public const prop1="Some";
}
public Class2
{
 public const prop1="Some";
}
```

And in my code I am getting my class name like this

```
string classname="Session["myclass"].ToString();";//Say I have Class1 now.
```

And I want to get the prop1 value .

```
Something like
 string mypropvalue=classname+".prop1";//my expected result is Some
```

///
     Type typ=Type.GetType(classname);

Please help me in getting this

Comment: you can use reflection to dynamically get property values from class name.

Comment: I am trying for the same but unable to get it right.

Comment: show code how you use reflection.

Comment: @slavoo actually my class is a static class...and I want to retrieve its property value dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

```
var nameOfProperty = "prop1";
var propertyInfo = Class1Object.GetType().GetProperty(nameOfProperty);
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null);
```

for static:

```
var nameOfProperty = "prop1";
var propertyInfo = typeof(Class1).GetProperty("prop1", BindingFlags.Static);
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null);
```

[Class reference from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string)

EDIT (I made example):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var list = Assembly.Load("ConsoleApplication4").GetTypes().ToList();
            Type ty = Type.GetType(list.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Foo").ToString());
            //This works too: Type ty = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication4.Foo");
            var prop1 
                 = ty.GetProperty("Temp", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);


            Console.WriteLine(prop1.GetValue(ty.Name, null));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public static class Foo
    {
        private static string a = "hello world";
        public static string Temp
        {
            get
            {
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx)

Comment: My classname is retrieved from session .

Comment: Thnks .It Worked For me..And Cant we access the "a" directly?

Comment: To access field "a" use: `var prop1 = ty.GetField("a", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
Console.WriteLine(prop1.GetValue(ty.Name));` but need set field "a" as public

Answer (score 0):

you can use following function to get a property value fron an object dynamically:
just pass object to scan & property name

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Comment: How to get the value of a static class Property

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487867/c-sharp-get-values-of-static-properties-from-static-class